# Only change session variable if GET request has value

Tags: php, session-variables

I am looking to set a session variable based on a search conducted by the user.  The idea is that the search is populated with their last search wherever they go on the site.

I have the following code that I thought would set the variable if the variable geo-box was present and use the saved variable if it isn't, but this doesn't work...

```
    session_start();

if(isset($_GET['geo-box'])){
    echo $_SESSION['town'] = $_GET['geo-box'];
} else {
    echo $_SESSION['town'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['geo-box']))
  $_SESSION['town'] = $_GET['geo-box'];

echo $_SESSION['town'];
```

You can't echo a variable while defining it.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to echo a variable and set it in the same line.

Try this:

```
session_start();

if( isset($_GET['geo-box']) ) {
    $_SESSION['town'] = $_GET['geo-box'];
}

echo $_SESSION['town'];
```

You can not echo a value and assign it at the same time. Give this a try!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why not put the echo statement outside?

Comment: Good point. Just noticed your answer, I agree with it and that would be the best answer in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks guys - have tried this and am still getting nothing on the pages where geo-box isn't present.

Comment: You would always get nothing if `$_GET['geo-box']` is not set as you are not setting the `$_SESSION['town']` anywhere else. Have you made sure that you add the `?geo-box=value` to the url?

Comment: Thanks Joe - I don't think i've explained myself very well.  I want to use the session variable to populate a search form that appears on all pages across the site.

I thought a session variable might be better than adding it to the url.

What I wanted my code to do is set the variable when it occurs on the search results page, and then this gets used across all other pages...

Comment: Ah, I see. All you need to do is set the `$_SESSION['value']` variable as you would any other variable, and access it as you would any other variable. So if `$_SESSION['geo-box']` is set somewhere in your code, and that piece of code is run, you will be able to access `$_SESSION['geo-box']` from any other piece of PHP code as long as the session persists. (Make sure you have `session_start()` on every page that you need to call the `$_SESSION` global from.

Comment: session_start();

if(isset($_GET['geo-box'])) {
  $_SESSION['town'] = $_GET['geo-box'];
}

else {
 $search = $_SESSION['town'];
}

Comment: I think something like that would work, but you would still have a problem that `$_SESSION['town']` would not always be set. `$_SESSION['town']` would only be set as long as someone passes `$_GET['geo-box']` to the script at some point (not every time, but at least once per session). So as long as that is passed, what you have should work. Echoing `$search` should output the value of `$_GET['geo-box']`.